# Gmail mailto with images and links

Tags: html, gmail, href, mailto

I need to create a mailto links, which automatically sets both the recipients and the body.
I'm fine as long as the body is just a plain text, but I need it to contain links and images (and the image needs to be linked).

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question?

Comment: I created a link like this one: mailto:mail@xx.com?bcc=mail@xx.com&subject=mysubject&body=mybody

I need to add links and image in the body of the mail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. You can't send MIME bodies in `mailto:` `body` parameter. Since body parameter is intended for only `plain/text` . You can't format the value into `HTML`. Send the mail programmatically using Emailer functions with support of `HTML` body